# RestKit mapping few object at one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api, restkit

When I'm sending get requests for a few objects, I'm receiving objects one by one.

I see that the mapping time increases for each object, so it looks like:

- 1st get request - 00:00
- 2nd get request - 00:00
- 3rd get request - 00:00
- 1st responce - 00:02
- 2nd responce - 00:04
- 3rd responce - 00:06

I believe that the API returns data in parallel. How can I set up RestKit to receive all objects at once? Like:

- 1st get request - 00:00
- 2nd get request - 00:00
- 3rd get request - 00:00
- 1st responce - 00:02
- 2nd responce - 00:02
- 3rd responce - 00:02

Comment: You need to provide more information and code. I'm guessing you have a serial queue somewhere you need to change that to a concurrent queue.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Mozahler no, do another stuff now. Will add some code few later.

Comment: *doing another stuff - my English isn't perfect :D